# google maps v3: zoom_changed called twice when zoom out of range

Tags: google-maps-api-3

In the basic sample code below I use the following code to catch zoom_changed event:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    console.log(map.getZoom());
});
```

If I call map.setZoom(30), I get this into console:

```
> map.setZoom(30)
> 30
> 21
```

That is, the zoom_changed is fired twice and once with incorrect value. It causes me some problems in libraries and I don't know why this happens. However, I can't reproduce the issue on some other projects with v3 api.

Strange thing is that if I specify the zoom_changed listener additionally in console instead of putting it into initialize, I get values: 21, 21. So the answer is there somehow.

The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple Map</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var map;
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
        console.log(map.getZoom());
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have filled a bug report: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6349&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal

Comment: You wrote `If I call map.getZoom(30)`, do you mean `map.setZoom(30)`?

Comment: [**WontFix**](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5003)